# Why is using the z-index not letting me put my image behind the background?

Tags: html, css, image

Here is my code:

```
    body {
        background: #ffc04c url("bark_360.jpg");
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
        z-index: 0;
    }

    img {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        z-index: -2;
    }
    </style>  
    <img src="goleafs.png" style="Padding-Left: 130px">
```

as you can see the img as the lower z-index as compared to the background....yet it is still on top when I refresh. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: You cannot be behind your parents.

It's not possible to have a lower zIndex than your parents in the DOM, what you will need to do is to create a div that holds the background image, this way your image can get behind:

```
<img src="goleafs.png" style="Padding-Left: 130px">
<div class="bg"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.bg {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #ffc04c url("bark_360.jpg");
}

img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -2;
}
```

Comment: Oh, ok I understand now. So I needed to create two separate entries in CSS and identify my background class wit the bg entry. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your `img` is INSIDE of `body`, so it goes on top of the `body`'s background. To achieve what you want to do, you should have two seperate `img`s, one for the background, and one for the actual image.

Try something like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      img {
        position: absolute;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <img src="url('bark_360.jpg')">
    <img src="url('goleafs.png')">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: so you are saying I should have the first body also replaced by img? I tried that but it didnt work it gave me something else